# Deciding which to scroll, document.documentElement or document.body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a page which has to scroll with animation to certain positions when something happens.

I'm applying `jQuery.animate` to `document.documentElement` and it seems to work properly on Firefox and some versions of IE, while on Chrome and other versions of IE it has to apply to `document.body` to work.

Am I being an idiot here? What am I missing? And if I'm not, what is the proper way to detect which one to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not an idiot, it has always been tricky, see comments [here](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) for example :)

As far as I remember, 
    `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '-=100'})`
works in all major browsers now.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the safe way to do this is running the animation on `document.documentElement`, `document.body` and `window` at once. One will work for sure.

Even though this solution is hideously ugly, it works in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

An easy to use plugin is scrollTo: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

otherwise you can typically use `$(window).animate();`

Comment: Nice plugin, I will definitely use it. But it still requires a jQuery object to run on, and that's the main issue here. I will give the `$(window)` a shot though.

Answer (score 0):

There are several very old methods (not standard but working in every browser): `window.scroll
()`, `window.scrollTo()`, `window.scrollBy()` and other. See e.g. this MDN page for documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Window.scroll

Note that while in Firefox or Chrome these methods just change scrollTop/scrollLeft and do not cause immediate scrolling (scrolling is delayed until javascript event handler returns), 
in Opera and IE these methods actually scroll the window immediately (which is not very good).

It would be so much better if all browsers could use the same element for scrolling though.